# While loop in shell script says [: too many arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, while-loop

I'm trying to run a very simple script that reads input from a user and continuously loop a question if the users input doesn't match what is expected.

It's being execute via bash:

```
echo "Specify a directory [Y/N]?"

read ans
while [ [ "$ans" != "Y" ] || [ "$ans" != "y" ] || [ "$ans" != "N" ] || [ "$ans" != "n" ] ]
do
    echo "$ans is not valid, please answer [Y/N]"
    read ans
done
```

code continues....

Any idea why this is not working?  It seems like a pretty straight forward loop.

Comment: You cannot nest `[...]` expressions inside each other.

Comment: To add to @chepner's comment - if you really do need grouping (in this case you don't - see Clement Rey's answer below), you need to use `(` and `)` instead (possibly with appropriate escaping/quoting, depending on your exact syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
echo "Specify a directory [Y/N]?" 
read ans 
while [ "$ans" != "Y" ] && [ "$ans" != "y" ] && [ "$ans" != "N" ] && [ "$ans" != "n" ]
do
    echo "$ans is not valid, please answer [Y/N]"
    read ans 
done
```

There were a few mistakes:

- you were probably thinking **AND** instead of **OR**
- there is no global `[ ]` for a multiconditionnal while loop

Comment: That allows my program to proceed without the endless loop but I still get the "[: too many arguments" error.  "

Comment: `&&` is the correct operator to use here, as `$ans` will *always* be unequal to one of the choices.

Comment: With `||`, he is going in no matter what so I guess he wanted a `&&`.